# Can I set a lock on files with google api?

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

when I look at Gdrive, there is also a fuse client to mount Gdrive. I wonder, when modifying a file on Gdrive through this client, is the file "locked" or in any other way set to "in use" to prevent others to modify the "original" on the internet? I haven't found anything about this. Isn't there a locking method with Google docs api?

Stef Bon

Answer (score 6):

There is no such feature, but you can use the [ETag of the file's entry](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#updatingchanging_documents_and_files) to ensure that no one else has changed the file since it was fetched. This is not exactly the same thing, but it can achieve the same effect of ensuring that changes from one place are not overwritten by changes from another place.

Comment: And now with Google Drive REST API v.3 even that possibility is gone - no more access to file ETag with v3. Thank you, Google, for making our lives more difficult every day!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure they don't have that. You should consider suggesting it in [the Google Docs feature request forums](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!forum/docs).