# Google Drive file simultaneous modification

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, synchronization

I am trying to make a simple "sync" functionality. Let me describe my problem with a simple example:

> Let's say there is a file named `lorem.txt` on Google Drive (appFolder). What happens if at the same time, two different devices (belonging to the same user with the same Google account) access the file and try to read or change the contents or name of the file? Lets say device A is suppose to make a change in the contents while device B is also trying to do the same at the same time. The file is accessed through it's unique ID.

How to go around this problem? **Is there a build in functionality or measures in place to avoid simultaneous write access to a file (like some sort of file lock)?**
I am specifically looking for a solution using Google JS SDK or using plain JS (with Authentication tokens ofc). Does the Drive server returns some sort of error status code (like 404) when such a scenario happens?

**UPDATE:**

Based on these previously asked questions (asked in 2017 and 2012 respectively):
[Android Drive Api Lock File while in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43755723/android-drive-api-lock-file-while-in-use)
and
[Can I set a lock on files with google api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561691/can-i-set-a-lock-on-files-with-google-api)
, I think it is fair to assume that there is no such functionality built-in into Google Drive.

I will leave this question as a reference for others.

Comment: This question is very broad and doesn't have a concise problem statement that is readily answerable, but for reference, Google Docs uses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation

Comment: @skyline3000 thanks for the link. My problem is concisely stated in the bold above. I am simply asking: Does Google Drive has some functionality that prevents simultaneous modification of a file (like responding with an error or bad response code)? If yes, then what is it? And if no, then some advice/tips to get started on how to make some sort of "lock".

Comment: Unfortunately, Google Drive does not have the functionality allowing you to lock a file while editing. You could either remove/re-grant access to the file before and after editing as a workaround, though this isn't ideal. Another workaround would be to implement a idea similar to the pull/merge requests you can make with git; create a buffer file which holds the old data and then compare the buffer with the on-Drive file again before pushing your updates via the API which can flag to see if the file has been edited by someone else at the same time.

Comment: there is indeed no lock mechanism. You could build one at the application level, but I suspect that will be troublesome. Better than conflict prevention using a lock, I would go for conflict detection using md5sum.

Comment: https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2020/10/lock-files-using-the-google-drive-api.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can use the `If-Match` header to only apply your updates if the file has not been modified concurrently: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/performance?#read-patch-write